# List showing empty Flutter Provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, provider

I'm adding an Object to the list after a call HTTP request, My problem is when I print the list just after insert a new list item, it's showing me the object but when I try to fetch the list item by the provider it's showing empty list.

Class-

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' as json;

enum LoginType { ME, YOU, WE }

class PlayerPrebsData {
  final String id;
  final int points;
  final String cookie;
  final Map data;
  final LoginType loginType;

  PlayerPrebsData({
    required this.id,
    required this.points,
    required this.cookie,
    required this.data,
    required this.loginType,
  });
}

class CookieLogin extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<PlayerPrebsData> _items = [];

  List<PlayerPrebsData> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }


  Future<void> login(String cookie, LoginType loginType,
      [String data = ""]) async {
    final url = Uri.parse("https://xxxxx.com/xxxxxx/v2/login.php");
    final response = await http.post(url, body: {
      'cookie': cookie,
      'loginType': loginType.toString(),
    });

    final body = json.jsonDecode(response.body);
    _items.add(
      PlayerPrebsData(
        id: body['data']['id'],
        points: body['data']['credit'],
        cookie: cookie,
        data: body['data'],
        loginType: loginType,
      ),
    );
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I'm calling it from a stateless class

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<CookieLogin>(context).items;
    //////// Scafford then my floating button
   floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        print(provider.length);
      },
      child: const Icon(Icons.navigation),
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    ));
```

When I click the button I got 0 length

Comment: where you call adding items?

Comment: After an HTTP request, I wait for a response then add the item to the list, Then instantly I call to check the list item using getter- getter returns a copy of the list. SO that mean item is added, but when I try to get data from list again its showing 0 items in the list

Comment: I think you'll need a method in the CookieLogin class where you add a PlayerPrebsData and call notifyListeners()